# Angular updating two different arrays when only one should be updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm still getting my feet wet with Angular, so keep that in mind as you read about my problem.

I have a series of dynamically generated checkboxes that can be used to grant permissions to other users. Whenever a checkbox is updated, it updates a $scope.permissions array that I have set up in my main controller. The array is populated by an AJAX request that fires when a user to administer is selected from a dropdown.

I want to notify the user if they have unsaved changes before they navigate away or change the user they are wanting to administer. So, I set up a second array called originalPermissions that is set to the same data as the $scopes.permission array, like so:

```
$http.post(ajaxurl, user_data)
          .success(function(data) {
            // Get the permissions model from the server and store to the $scope
            console.log('Setting');
            $scope.permissions = data;
            $scope.origPermissions = data;
...}
```

Then, each of the checkboxes have an `ng-click="updatePermission(data.path)"` function call. It likes like this:

```
$scope.updatePermission = function (path) {
    //get the position of the target path in the array
    var position = $scope.permissions.indexOf(path);
    //if it doesn't exist, its position will be -1
    if(position == -1){
        // Push the path into the Array if it doesn't exist
        $scope.permissions.push(path);
    } else {
        // Remove the permission from the array if it was already there
        $scope.permissions.splice(position, 1);
    }

    console.log('Perms: '+$scope.permissions);
    console.log('OldPerms: '+$scope.origPermissions);
}
```

Even though I am only performing pushes on the `$scope.permissions` array, the `$scope.origPermissions` array is getting updated as well (the console.logs are outputting identical things). This is not desirable, because I want to see if the new stuff in permissions is different from what we have in origPermissions; if so, I want to fire a confirmation box saying "You have unsaved changes..." etc.

That said, I know watchCollection() exists in angular, but as far as I understand, watchCollection notifies you whenever the permissions array changes, but there's no way to tell if it is the same as it was when originally set.

So: why would origPermissions get updated along with scope? Is it because I'm setting each array to the same value, so Angular is assuming it's essentially the same thing? Is there a better way to do this that's more in keeping with the "Angular way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $scope.permissions = data;
     $scope.origPermissions = data;
```

data "points" to the same array.

You can use slice to return a new array

```
     $scope.permissions = data.slice();
     $scope.origPermissions = data;
```

Comment: Awesome. That makes it work as I'm expecting. I was wondering if it was a "pointer" problem, but I didn't know that was a 'thing' in JavaScript. Can you tell me: is this common JS behavior, or is this something Angular is doing?

Comment: It's because of javascript , not angular. Arrays are kindof a collection of pointers like in C.